# the Position of Adjectives

Tags: adjectives, word-order, nouns

Can an adjective come after a noun? For example;

Deep caverns 
/Caverns deep

What 's the difference between them? 
What's the purpose of the second one? Why do we use it?

Comment: Did you try using the "Search Q&A" field? It works like this: you enter a phrase in the field, such as _"Adjective before or after a noun"_, and then press the "enter" key.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, adjectives do not follow the noun they modify. However, it is useful in poetry to switch adjectives and nouns for added emphasis on the phrase. For example, when I read "caverns deep", there is an extra emphasis on the cavern being deep. But this would only really work in a poetic/musical sense; it would be weird in colloquial speech.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#In_modern_English) is the Wikipedia explanation of these kinds of phrasings.